# Validation that accept only small alphabets and '-' in yii2

Tags: validation, model, yii2

In my text box I want to allow only small alphabets and '-' symbol.

How can I make it possible in a yii2 model?

I already tried this:

```
['slug', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z-]/', 'message' => 'Slug contain only small alphabets and - symbol'],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this its work for me

```
 [['slug'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z-]+$/', 'message' => 'Slug Contain only small alphabets and - symbol']
```